# openfoam v2006 wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found

Tags: libstdc++, ubuntu-20.04, openfoam, wsl-2

Since I installed according to the guide [here](https://openfoam.com/download/install-windows-10.php) on wsl2 ubuntu 20.04, I've been having errors related to `libstc++.so.6`, specifically `GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found (required by ...)` where ... refers to different files within `/opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v2006/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/` ending in `.so`, `.so.1`, `.so.6` and so on (for instance, when running `paraFoam` the error would appear with respect to about 20 such files). I am able to successfully visualize the cavity tutorial (in paraview installation on windows).

I could get the errors to go away by doing what the user *laborg* suggested on Jan 4 for a similar problem with julia (see [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/glibcxx-3-4-26-not-found-in-rcall/29113/10)), specifically copy libstdc++.so.6 from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `/opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v2006/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/`.

**The questions is** whether this copy-paste solution is recommended; will it come back and haunt me later? Is the `libstdc++.so.6` from system installation going to be an issue if used in the lib64 folder of openfoam?

An additional info concerning openfoam installation, `foamInstallationTest` shows `*not installed*` errors against `flex`, `wmake`, `gcc`, `g++`, `icoFoam` and `*critical error*` for `gcc`, `g++`, `icoFoam`; but I as given [here](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/90537-foaminstallationtest.html), `foamInstallationTest` is not meant for installation from the tar file. Openfoam installation seems to be alright based on the running of the cavity tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

ok, please don't do copy past operation to solve this problem. The error means that you haven't installed the pre request libraries in your ubuntu. It seems that you have missed the first step in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended but it will not hurt as long as the GLIBC versions returned from this command

`strings /opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v2006/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC`

are a subset of the GLIBC versions from this command.

`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC`

which was no doubt the case for your Ubuntu setup.

---

A less risky route would be to redirect the soft link /opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v2006/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 to point to your other libstdc++.so.6 (that way you retain both versions)

`ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v2006/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`

Then, if you hit an issue, you can always reset the link back to its original target. Of course `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` is itself a soft link, but you can point to it all the same or you can point to its target.

---

I believe the issue you are hitting is a derivative of the one mentioned here https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/main/229027-persistence-glibcxx_3-4-26-not-found.html, which would point towards the fact that it is not an installation error on your part but an issue related to the packaging of the OpenFoam binaries. I agree it would screw up the wsl2 setup owing to the way OpenFoam prepends everything to paths. Of course the safest route is to compile from source using the Ubuntu system's gcc and thereby bypass the ThirdParty.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using Ubuntu in the WSL instance, could also just install the Ubuntu package **directly**:

https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/precompiled/debian

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from this line in the tutorial:

```
echo "source /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/etc/bashrc" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will point to OpenFOAM's libstdc++ everytime you open a terminal (or start a WSL2 session). If your workflow is not related to OpenFOAM, that can be an issue. If you remove or comment that line in your ~/.bashrc things should get back to normal. You can use nano in WSL2.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then comment:

```
#source /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/etc/bashrc
```

However, as OpenFOAM uses that bashrc, you will need to source the OpenFOAM bashrc in each terminal before using openFOAM.

```
source /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/etc/bashrc
```

My personal choice is to keep that line commented and, if I have a long work session using OpenFOAM, I just use *nano* to uncomment it, so every shell that I open works without sourcing again.

There are more elegant or complex approaches, but I prefer this one.

This answer should be valid with the 2006 version too, the link you shared points to 2012, so I guess they just updated the tutorial. If you installed 2006, just make sure when you source comment/uncomment to use the correct name.

In the same manner, if you followed another tutorial with another tool and sourced another library, you may experience issues.

Just start by taking a look at your bashrc and cleaning it.